# I am getting a Radix out of range exception on performing decryption

Tags: java, exception, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I am generating a keypair and converting one of the same into string which later is inserted into the database using the following code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair generatedKeyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
PublicKey pubkey = generatedKeyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey prvkey = generatedKeyPair.getPrivate();
System.out.println("My Public Key>>>>>>>>>>>"+pubkey);
System.out.println("My Private Key>>>>>>>>>>>"+prvkey);
String keyAsString = new BigInteger(prvkey.getEncoded()).toString(64);
```

I then retrieve the string from the database and convert it back to the original key using the following code (where rst is my ResultSet):

```
String keyAsString = rst.getString("privateKey").toString();
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(keyAsString, 64).toByteArray();
//byte k[] = "HignDlPs".getBytes(); 
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes); 
KeyFactory rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");  
PrivateKey privKey = rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);
```

On using the privKey for RSA decryption, I get the following exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Radix out of range
at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:294)
at com.util.SimpleFTPClient.downloadFile(SimpleFTPClient.java:176)
at com.Action.FileDownload.processRequest(FileDownload.java:64)
at com.Action.FileDownload.doGet(FileDownload.java:94)
```

Please guide.

Comment: I am not sure about that. How do I check. Its a huge number

Comment: Careful - [`toString(int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-) _ignores_ the radix and uses `10` if it's not within the valid range of 2 thru 36.

Comment: can you help me enhance my code to avoid this exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an exception because the radix you're providing *is* greater than [`Character.MAX_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX) (which is 36). In other words, it's entirely predictable.

Don't use `BigInteger` as an encoding class. That's not what it's there for. There are *plenty* of decent ways of performing base64 encoding. Personally I like [this public domain library](http://iharder.net/base64).

```
String keyAsString = Base64.encode(prvkey.getEncoded());
```

Then later:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(keyAsString);
```

Comment: I get a warning that says No suitable method found for decode and something like actual and formal argument list differ in length.

Comment: @user3672391: That suggests you're using a different Base64 class, rather than the one from the link in my answer.

Comment: @user3672391: why not? That comment on its own gives us almost no information. If you want help, you need to put more effort into helping us to help you...

Comment: I downloaded the file. Where should I keep those files at, I mean which folder. I am a novice in Java. Please help.

Comment: @user3672391: It's just a Java file. Put it in a folder which matches the package declared at the top of the file. If this is too much for you, I would *strongly* advise you to step away from your current project and learn the basics of Java. It's much safer than continuing with security-related code (of all things) when you're not confident in the language you're using.